# LaTeX adding a vertical caption with listing

Tags: latex

Is there a way where I can add a vertical caption with `listings` in LaTeX as TC1 in the following:

[image]

What I did is:

```
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\fontsize{7}{8}\ttfamily},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3
}

\lstinputlisting[language=Java]{./TC1.java}
```

How can I add TC1 in the listing?